SortableJS - Drag element into sibling as a child
I'm new to using SortableJS, so I'm not sure if this is by design or if I'm doing it wrong.
I can drag elements to be children of elements that already have at least one child element, but I cannot drag them into elements that don't have any children.  And if I drag all the elements out of an element so that it has none, I cannot drag them back into that element again.
Here's my code; I can drag anything to be a child of Home, PHP Support, or PHP 7 Support. Nothing else will accept a child element.


$(document).ready(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll("#category-list ul").forEach(function(listEl) {
    new Sortable(listEl, {
      group: "nested",
      handle: ".handle",
      animation: 150,
      fallbackOnBody: true,
      swapThreshold: 0.65,
      onEnd: function(evt) {
        var order = [];
        $("#category-list li").each(function(index, element) {
          order.push({
            id: $(element).data("id"),
            parent_id: $(element).closest("ul").closest("li").data("id") || null,
            position: index
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.6.0/css/fontawesome.min.css";
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.6.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.15.2/Sortable.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container" id="handle">
      <ul class="list-group" id="category-list">
        <li class="list-group-item" data-id="17"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>Home<ul>
            <ul class="list-group" id="category-list">
              <li class="list-group-item" data-id="15"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>Test Forum</li>
              <li class="list-group-item" data-id="9"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>Hosting Support</li>
              <li class="list-group-item" data-id="21"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>Forum</li>
              <li class="list-group-item" data-id="10"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>PHP Support<ul>
                  <ul class="list-group" id="category-list">
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="18"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>PHP 7 Support<ul>
                        <ul class="list-group" id="category-list">
                          <li class="list-group-item" data-id="20"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>HTAccess</li>
                        </ul>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="11"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>PHP 8 Support</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="19"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>MySQL Support</li>
                  </ul>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>




I was able to solve the issue by adjusting my code a bit. This script ensures that all list items, even those without children, have a nested ul element initialized. This way, I can drag elements to any list item, regardless of whether it initially has children.


function initializeSortable(el) {
        new Sortable(el, {
            group: 'nested',
            animation: 150,
            handle: ".handle",
            fallbackOnBody: true,
            swapThreshold: 0.65,
            onEnd: function (evt) {
                var order = [];
                $('#category-list li').each(function (index, element) {
                    order.push({
                        id: $(element).data('id'),
                        parent_id: $(element).closest('ul').closest('li').data('id') || null,
                        position: index
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }

    document.querySelectorAll('#category-list ul').forEach(function (listEl) {
        initializeSortable(listEl);
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('#category-list li').forEach(function (listItem) {
        if (!listItem.querySelector('ul')) {
            var newUl = document.createElement('ul');
            newUl.classList.add('list-group');
            listItem.appendChild(newUl);
            initializeSortable(newUl);
        }
    });
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.6.0/css/fontawesome.min.css";
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.6.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.15.2/Sortable.min.js"></script>


<ul class="list-group" id="category-list">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="17"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>Home
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" data-id="15"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>Test Forum</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" data-id="21"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>Forum</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" data-id="10"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>PHP Support
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="11"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>PHP 8 Support</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-id="18"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>PHP 7 Support
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" data-id="20"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>HTAccess</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item" data-id="19"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>MySQL Support</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" data-id="9"><i class="fa-solid fa-up-down-left-right handle pe-2"></i>Hosting Support</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>



